# How to use a single playback Activity for PiP?

Tags: android, kotlin, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

While I play a content with a different url while PiP mode is on, the old content is playing.

I made all the suggested adjustments in the file `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
    <activity
            android:name=".presentation.ui.player.live.LivePlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
            android:excludeFromRecents="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:parentActivityName=".presentation.ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:resizeableActivity="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            tools:targetApi="n" />
        <activity
```

The same content plays even though I click on a different element in the `RecyclerView`. It does not work correctly when PiP mode is running.

```kotlin
private val onChannelSelectedListener = object : ChannelAdapter.OnChannelSelectedListener {
        override fun onChannelSelected(channel: Channel) {        
            activity?.let { startActivity(LivePlayerActivity.newIntent(it, channelId = channel.id)) }
        }
    }
```

In this class, many features have been added for PiP mode operation. It works flawlessly.
`BasePlayerActivity.kt`

```kotlin
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun playPipMode() {
    pictureInPicturePlayContent(true)
    updatePictureInPictureActions(
        R.drawable.ic_player_pause,
        "",
        CONTROL_TYPE_PAUSE,
        REQUEST_PAUSE
    )
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun pausePipMode() {
    pictureInPicturePlayContent(false)
    updatePictureInPictureActions(
        R.drawable.ic_player_play,
        "",
        CONTROL_TYPE_PLAY,
        REQUEST_PLAY
    )
}

fun enterPictureInPicture(isUserAction: Boolean = false) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (pictureInPictureParamsBuilder == null) {
            pictureInPictureParamsBuilder = PictureInPictureParams.Builder()
        }
        pictureInPictureParamsBuilder?.apply {
            setAspectRatio(Rational(16, 9))
            updatePictureInPictureActions(
                R.drawable.ic_player_pause,
                "",
                CONTROL_TYPE_PAUSE,
                REQUEST_PAUSE
            )
        }?.let {
            enterPictureInPictureMode(it.build())
        }
    }
    if (isUserAction) {
        navToLauncherTask()
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun updatePictureInPictureActions(
    @DrawableRes iconId: Int,
    title: String,
    controlType: Int,
    requestCode: Int
) {
    val actions = arrayListOf<RemoteAction>()
    val pendingIntentFlag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
         PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    } else {
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    }
    val intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        this,
        requestCode,
        Intent(ACTION_MEDIA_CONTROL).putExtra(EXTRA_CONTROL_TYPE, controlType),
        pendingIntentFlag
    )
    val icon = Icon.createWithResource(this, iconId)
    actions.add(RemoteAction(icon, title, title, intent))
    pictureInPictureParamsBuilder?.apply {
        setActions(actions)
    }?.let {
        setPictureInPictureParams(it.build())
    }
}

override fun onPictureInPictureModeChanged(
    isInPictureInPictureMode: Boolean,
    newConfig: Configuration
) {
    super.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode, newConfig)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (isInPictureInPictureMode) { // Starts receiving events from action items in PiP mode.
            registerPipModeReceivers()
        } else if (!this.isInPictureInPictureMode) {
            errorPopupRunnable?.run()
            errorPopupRunnable = null
            cancelAudioMode(isOnStop)
            unRegisterPipModeReceivers()
        }
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun registerPipModeReceivers() {
    registerReceiver(pictureInPictureActionReceiver, IntentFilter(ACTION_MEDIA_CONTROL))
    if (pipModeAudioFocus == null) {
        pipModeAudioFocus = getPipModeAudioFocus()
    }
    pipModeAudioFocus?.let { audioManager.requestAudioFocus(it) }
}

private fun unRegisterPipModeReceivers() {
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(pictureInPictureActionReceiver)
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        pipModeAudioFocus?.let { audioManager.abandonAudioFocusRequest(it) }
    }
}
```

What should I do?